# Connections entity - Audit menu missing

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

We have migrated a CRM 2011 successfully to Dynamics 365, Version 9.
We have determined that the audit history for connections is not present in the UI.

Is it because the connection form is still in CRM 2011 style (out-of-the-box)? If so, where do you find the connection audit history?

Auditing is enabled in CRM, on the connection entity and also some fields are configured for auditing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume this is expected behavior & working as per design in various CRM versions.

`Connection` entity Form editor showing left navigation with "Audit History" menu.

> [image]

Actual `Connection` form rendering is not showing the left navigation. I remember [this was the case with CRM 2011 form also](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/06/03/toward-a-360-degree-view-of-the-customer-connections-in-crm-2011/).

> [image]

If you want to show the "Audit history" explicitly, you can always go for some **unsupported** solution [like discussed here](https://www.crmug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=1285&MessageKey=0d1a93c7-ac97-43ca-9241-5f2149ae2b10&CommunityKey=dc83c23b-ede0-4070-ae7a-dd90859148a6&tab=digestviewer#bm0d1a93c7-ac97-43ca-9241-5f2149ae2b10).

Keep an `iframe` & point the url something like this: (Obviously you have to script to parameterize it)

```
https://devcrm.crm.dynamics.com/userdefined/areas.aspx?formid=52078acf-77c4-4e18-86b8-ebffcafc0698&inlineEdit=1&navItemName=Audit History&oId={3877A32E-EA20-E911-A952-000D3A34E213}&oType=3234&pagemode=iframe&rof=true&security=852023&tabSet=areaAudit&theme=Outlook15White
```

Code from the above UG discussion link:

```
function buildIframeSource() {
            var url = window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
            var recordId = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
            var element = document.getElementById("areaAuditFrame");
            element.src = url + "/userdefined/areas.aspx?formid=52078acf-77c4-4e18-86b8-ebffcafc0698&inlineEdit=1&navItemName=Audit%20History&oId=%7b" + recordId + "%7d&oType=10270&pagemode=iframe&rof=true&security=852023&tabSet=areaAudit&theme=Outlook15White";
        };
```